# How to store Devbridge Autocomplete instance into a javascript variable, for reuse

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

In version 1.1.3 of Devbridge Autocomplete, I could put the autocomplete instance into a variable "a1" for instance, and use that variable in other part of my page (for instance, to disable the autocomplete functionality).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var a1;

   function fn_disable() {
      a1.disable();
   }


    $(function() {

                 a1 = $('#tablename').autocomplete({
                            serviceUrl:'/lookup',
                            minChars:3,
                            delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, 
                            maxHeight:400,
                            width:520,
                            zIndex: 9999,
                            deferRequestBy: 50, 
                            noCache: false
                       });
             });                 
  </script>
```

This seems to not work in version 1.2.6.
I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: a1.disable() is not a function.
Inside fn_disable(), variable a1 seems to be undefined, but the autocomplete is working well.

Is it not posible anymore? 
Can someone see if something is not correct in the above script ?
Thanks per advance

Comment: When do you call `fn_disable()` function exactly, it seems you are trying to call it, while at the same time autocomplete plugin still not loaded yet. Also you can try `$('#tablename').autocomplete('disable');`

Comment: I use fn_disable() by clicking on a form checkbox element, after the page was loaded. 

Even this simple script, where a1.disable() follows directly the autocomplete statement does not work. . Thanks per advance.



<script type="text/javascript">
   var a1;

    $(function() {

                 a1 = $('#tablename').autocomplete({
                            serviceUrl:'/lookup',
                            minChars:3,
                       });
                      a1.disable();   //   # <==== I am getting error here
             });                 
  </script>
```